# Laravel QR reader not using .vue file

Tags: laravel, qr-code

I installed gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader package for reading QR codes.

this is my qrscan.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Vue</title>
        <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div> 
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue' 
import VueQrcodeReader from 'vue-qrcode-reader'

Vue.use(VueQrcodeReader)

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App },
});
```

and my vue-qrcode-reader.vue

```
<template>
  <QrcodeReader
    :paused="paused"
    @decode="onDecode"
    @init="onInit">
    <div v-if="content" class="decoded-content">{{ content }}</div>

    <LoadingIndicator v-show="loading" />
  </QrcodeReader>
</template>

<script>
import { QrcodeReader } from 'vue-qrcode-reader'
import InitHandler from '@/mixins/InitHandler'
export default {
  components: { QrcodeReader },
  mixins: [ InitHandler ],
  data () {
    return {
      paused: false,
      content: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onDecode (content) {
      this.content = content
      this.paused = true
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.
.
.
</style>
```

And this is my route

```
Route::get('/qrscan', 'InventoryItemController@QRscan');
```

What am I doing wrong? All i get is blank page its like my .vue file is not detected by my blade.php file.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so there are a few issues. Mainly in `app.js`. To start off when you are creating your vue instance you are referencing an unknow variable `App`. I assume this is your root component, but you've never imported it, so Vue doesn't know this.

Secondly, you have not imported your component in the `app.js` for the qr reader - `vue-qrcode-reader.vue`. Thus, it is not loaded and not usable.

And thirdly Vue is never being rendered. Why? You haven't rendered it when creating the Vue instance, nor in the blade file by referencing some Vue component.

So how could the fixed code look? app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue' 
import VueQrcodeReader from 'vue-qrcode-reader'
import VueQrCodeReaderComponent from './components/vue-qrcode-reader.vue'

Vue.use(VueQrcodeReader)
Vue.component('vue-qr-code-reader', VueQrCodeReaderComponent);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Now your Vue instance knows about the existence of your QR code reader component and we can reference it in the blade file to render it like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Vue</title>
        <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <vue-qr-code-reader></vue-qr-code-reader>
        </div> 
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So now, your app.js imports the `vue-qrcode-reader.vue` which is your component, binds it to "html" tag `<vue-qr-code-reader>` using the `Vue.component` method and then we can use it in our blade file. Don't forget to recompile your javascript and hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you launch `npm run build` or `yarn build` command ?

Because you need first to compile your file before using it in the navigator.
If you want to update the build each time you save a file, use `npm run watch` or `yarn watch`.

Your .vue file will not be loaded by the navigator, it will be compiled in a classic javascript file.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: When i run `npm run build` i get error `missing script: build`

Comment: Sorry it's `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`

Comment: Oh, I did that. Still nothing.

Comment: Ok can you show me your webpack.mix.js  ? Maybe you load `mix('js/app.js')` but in the public path it's only `mix('app.js')`

Comment: `let mix = require('laravel-mix'); mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use try the following code

```js
//routers.js
import VueQrcodeReader from './components/VueQrcodeReader.vue';
export default  [
  {
      name: 'VueQrcodeReader',
      path: '/',
      component: VueQrcodeReader
  }

];

//app.js
import Vue from 'Vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
import App from './App.vue';
import outroutes from './routers';

const router = new VueRouter({mode:'history', routes: outroutes});
new Vue(Vue.util.extend({router},App)).$mount('#app');
```

```html
//qrscan.blade.php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta https-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
        <title>Laravel Vuejs</title>
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
             
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</html>

//you create show.blade.php
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <VueQrcodeReader ></VueQrcodeReader >
                </div>
        </div>
@endsection

//you App.vue
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <transition name="fade">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </transition>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
  
<style>
    .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
      transition: opacity .5s
    }
    .fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
      opacity: 0
    }
</style>
  
<script>
  
    export default{
    }
```

You can see:https://hoanguyenit.com/send-mail-using-laravel-5-4-vuejs.html